# Why does the base case returning 1 sums up all the possible paths in this recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to understand the following recursive code. The problem is when given a grid find all the possible paths from top left (0,0) to the bottom right. You can only move down or move right. All the "X" are marked as walls and you can not traverse through.

## Example:

```
grid = [
  ["O", "O", "X"],
  ["O", "O", "O"],
  ["O", "O", "O"],
]
count_paths(grid) # -> 5
```

## Implementation:

```
def count_paths(grid):
  return _count_paths(grid,0,0,{})

def _count_paths(grid,r,c,memo):
  pos = (r,c)
  if pos in memo:
    return memo[pos]
  
  
  if not 0 <= r <len(grid) or not 0<= c < len(grid[0]) or grid[r][c]=="X":
    return 0
  
  if r == len(grid)-1 and c == len(grid[0])-1:
    return 1
  
  down_count = _count_paths(grid, r+1,c,memo)
  right_count = _count_paths(grid,r,c+1,memo)
  memo[pos] = down_count + right_count
  return down_count + right_count
```

This function works but I am not understanding how the answer is returning all the possible paths. If the base case returns 1 and if on the first two recursive iteration returns **down_count + right_count = 2**. Why does the next recursive call add 2 to itself: **2 + down_count + right_count**. I assumed the 2 would get lost and it should only do down_count+ right count again.

Comment: Uh?  Where is this code `2 + down_count + right_count` that you're referring to?  This solution is dynamic programming.  _count_paths() returns

Comment: And do you understand dynamic programming?  If so, this program is easy to explain.  It's just recursively calculating count_paths(x, y) = count_paths(x + 1, y) + count_paths(x, y+1), but cacheing the results.  If you don't understand dynamic programming, then maybe read up on it and come back.

Comment: I understand the memoization and dynamic programming concept, but I am trying to understand  how the recursive call stack works. If the call stack first returns 2 that is if down_count is 1 and right_count is one, on the next element in the stack how does it know to add 2 to the return statement "down_count  + right_count"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting a bit hung up on `down_count` and `right_count`.  They are just internal variables. The actual value you care about is the implicit `result` which is `down_count + right_count`.

If I were writing this code, I would have written:

```
result = _count_paths(grid, r + 1, c, memo) + _count_paths(grid, r, c+1, memo)
memo[(r, c)] = result
return result
```

which makes it clear that I'm memoizing the result, and that's all I care about.

Actually, if I were writing this code, I would have written:

```
from functools import cache

def count_paths(grid):
    @cache
    def _count_paths(r, c):
        if not 0 <= r < len(grid) or not 0 <= c < len(grid[0]) or grid[r][c] == "X":
            return 0
        if r == len(grid) - 1 and c == len(grid[0]) - 1:
            return 1
        return _count_paths(r + 1, c) + _count_paths(r, c + 1)

    return _count_paths(0, 0)
```

Let Python do the cacheing for me.